# I want to set the initial value to a primary key which is also set to the auto increment option such as it begins from the value 7899 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I want to set the initial value to a primary key which is also set to the auto increment option such and it begins from the value 7899?

Comment: it helped me thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT=7899;
```